# keyboardWasShown method not being called on my UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a UITextView and I implemented a keyboardWasShownMethod like so:

```
(void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect bkgndRect = inkTextField.superview.frame;
    bkgndRect.size.height += kbSize.height;
    [inkTextField.superview setFrame:bkgndRect];
    [inkScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, inkTextField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height) animated:YES];
     inkTextField.frame=CGRectMake(1, -5, 285, 221);
    NSLog(@"Called keyBoardWasShwon");
}
```

But for some reason it's not getting called when my keyboard appears. This method is in the same class as the UITextView and the UITextView is declared in the .h file and connected in XIB. What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you add the observer for *UIKeyboardWillShowNotification*?

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
                     addObserver:self 
                        selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) 
                            name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                          object:nil];
```

Comment: I was trying with this solution but it did not worked if I put self in the last parameter. Setting nil it worked like a charm.

Comment: @Mithu, Sorry. That was my mistake. That should be nil or the textView instance. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Turned out it was because I didn't have these in my code:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasHidden:) name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

}



- (void) viewWillDisappear: (BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc removeObserver:self name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [nc removeObserver:self name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```